# Sublime text, write multiple lines with increasing numbers

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime text, by selecting multiple lines, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicking multiple lines, I can edit all of them at the same time. What I would like, is that the numbers in those rows would be different; increase with each line.

Currently, for example, I would select 6 lines, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to get multiple cursors on each of them, then write for example `article > h1 { font-weight:normal; }`, and what comes out is:

```
article > h1 { font-weight:normal; }
article > h1 { font-weight:normal; }
article > h1 { font-weight:normal; }
article > h1 { font-weight:normal; }
article > h1 { font-weight:normal; }
article > h1 { font-weight:normal; }
```

And from here, if I want this to apply to all elements from `h1` through `h6`, I will edit each line manually to change the number.

So my question is, can Sublime Text output an increasing number in each line in this scenario? Or is there another, easier way of changing them manually after they had all been set to 1's?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several packages that help you to insert number sequence, including [Text Pastry](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Text%20Pastry), [Insert Nums](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Insert%20Nums) and so on.

If you use Text Pastry for example, you can achieve what you want by:

1. Select 6 lines.
2. Type `article > h`.
3. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to open the Text Pastry command line.
4. Enter `1` and press `enter`.
5. Type `{ font-weight:normal; }`.

Step 3 and 4 will insert a sequence `1, 2, ...` into your current selections.

Comment: cmd + alt + n nothing opening in sublime Text 3

Comment: @KrishnaKumarSingh You need to install Text Pastry extension first

Comment: Insert Nums is a game changer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Nobody is probably interested in this anymore, but you can do this without any plugins. Put your cursors where you want the numbers to appear. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command panel, type `Arithmetic` and then `i + 1` to start at one or simply `i` to start at zero. Hit enter.

Comment: What an absolute killer feature. Thank you sharing!